# iis7 website application not working

Tags: iis-7, web, http-status-code-403

i have a website of aspx on IIS7 and inside it is one directory which i have created into an application. It is the exact same setup as in another computer. the same code works fine there. it does not open the application here. i get a 403.1 error when i browse application by itself.
what are the palces that i can check that it is going wrong? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

403.1 is a security error, it is permissions.

```
HTTP 403.1 Forbidden: Execute Access Forbidden
```

Make sure the NETWORK SERVICE account has execute permission on that directory.

In the IIS Manager under the application's basic setting you can test your settings.